# how to use the given mono patch

Tags: mono

how to use the given mono patch . For example i have a patch like given below
https://bugzillafiles.novell.org/attachment.cgi?id=291049

This is  the patch for a bug in mono. how do i use it in mono.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

First off, this patch was clearly made against Mono SVN, which means it must be pretty old, as Mono moved to git some time ago.  The patch may not apply.

But to answer your question, you cannot patch your existing installation of Mono.  You will need to download the Mono source, apply the patch, and build it yourself.

If you are a Linux user, it is very important to keep this source install of Mono separate from your package install.  Follow these instructions to set up a "parallel" Mono environment:

http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments

To apply your patch, after you grab the Mono source code, you need to:

1. `cd mono` (or whatever the name of the directory containing mono source is)
2. `cd mcs` (because this patch was made against the `mcs` module before it was merged into the `mono` module
3. `patch -p0 < downloaded.patch` (to apply the the patch file to the `mcs` source)

Then proceed with the build instructions, and when you test, make sure you are in your parallel environment.

If you need help, I recommend joining the #mono IRC channel on irc.gnome.org.